# IE stopped working if coded ui tests executed continuously

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, .net-reflector

I am executing 25 Coded UI dlls continuously(One by one) using .NET Reflector. Approximately they have 6000 actions. After executed 10 to 15 dlls , The IE gets crashed & throws a Pop-up "Internet Explorer has stopped working". Its occurring randomly and not for any Particular script or action.

I am using VS2012 Ultimate for Recording . Using MS Test Agent 2012 for Playback and using IE 11. Scripts are recorded in C# language.

Kindly help to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this happen when running the web site locally or deployed somewhere.  Where are the tests being run from.  Are you "Running" the tests or "Debugging" them.

Comment: Website is deployed somewhere. Tests are being run from a local machine that has Windows 7,IE11,Ms Test Agent 2012. Am running(through a Windows Tool) them.

Comment: sounds like u have a good setup.  are you able to close the browser window on cleanup and have it open again with each test or does that break your test flow?  (I personally write tests such that every test opens the browser and navigates to where it needs to start so that there are no dependencies).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I am closing the browser window once a dll is executed completely. But I don't clear browsing history(Because meanwhile another website is opened in a separate Browser window)

Comment: When manually testing does this ever occur?  It doesn't seem to be related to coded ui or your test structure from what I can tell.

Comment: No. When manually testing it won't occur. This happens only when running continuously. Even when I am running each dll individually,there is no issues. This happens only when running continuously.

Comment: what do you mean by dlls? are they test methods?

Comment: Yes. Dynamic link Library(.dll) created inside Coded UI Test Project's Bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Some times long time time execution can cause this on IE. I too faced such issues during execution, i don't have a proper resolution for this. But what i did is implement below line of code after each test case

```
BrowserWindow.ClearCache();
BrowserWindow.ClearCookies();
BrowserWindow.SetFocus();
BrowserWindow.Refresh();
```